# How to update a table inside AFTER INSERT trigger on different table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a table `DISPENSE_DOSAGES` and created an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on this table. Inside that trigger, I am trying to update another table `DISPENSE_DRUGS` having matching rows with `INSERTED` table. when a row is inserted into `DISPENSE_DOSAGES` trigger fired successfully but it does not update rows in `DISPENSE_DRUGS`. I know this line is generating issue.

```
WHERE [DISPENSE_ID] IN (SELECT [DISPENSE_ID] FROM INSERTED)
```

`(SELECT [DISPENSE_ID] FROM INSERTED)` line in the above code is generating problem.

I know trigger called for batch inserts and tried a cursor solution but it does not work for me.

Here is the code for trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_DISPENSE_DOSAGES]
ON [dbo].[DISPENSE_DOSAGES] 
AFTER INSERT     
AS
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT [DISPENSE_ID]
                FROM INSERTED
                WHERE [DISPENSE_ID] IN (SELECT [DISPENSE_ID] 
                                        FROM [DISPENSE_DOSAGES]
                                        WHERE [SEPARATE_ITEM] = 1)))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[DISPENSE_DRUGS]
        SET QUANTITY_DISPENSED = 0,
            QUANTITY_OWED = QUANTITY_PRESCRIBED
        WHERE [DISPENSE_ID] IN (SELECT [DISPENSE_ID] FROM INSERTED)  --This line generates issue
    END
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Trigger fires correctly as well as IF condition comes True. but Update statement is not working.

Comment: Your description does not match the code - you say you have a trigger on DISPENSE_DOSAGES, but the code is a trigger on DISPENSE_DRUGS?

Comment: What is the error message or issue? Why you know `WHERE [DISPENSE_ID] IN (SELECT [DISPENSE_ID] FROM INSERTED)` is causing the issue?

Comment: @JamesCasey - could be the issue since you can't update the table in a trigger of the table itself (would be recursive).

Comment: Sorry, @JamesCasey It was old code. Now I had updated it with DISPENSE_DOSAGES.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch This is not the case. Actually trigger is on DISPENSE_DOSAGES table

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I passed a single ID(343597781504) replacing **(SELECT [DISPENSE_ID] FROM INSERTED)** statement and it worked fine.

Comment: I think someone elses edit has changed it back. As an aside, is a trigger the right way to do this? Could you instead wrap the insert and associated update in the other table into a stored procedure?

Comment: @JamesCasey but if there are multiple rows in INSERTED TABLE how I can pass them all to procedure in order to update values in DISPENSE_DRUGS table

Comment: Table valued parameter?

Comment: Procedure not working @JamesCasey

Comment: Your `exists` test includes a condition `where Separate_Item = 1` that is not part of the `update`. If anything that would cause the `update` to affect more rows, but it still seems odd. There are matching `Dispense_Id` values in both `Dispense_Dosages` and `Dispense_Drugs` tables, i.e. they are not `identity` columns in both tables, right? In general you should include the DDL for any tables in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problem is your table on creating Trigger.

Try this, as you are saying you are creating trigger on `DISPENSE_DOSAGES` but in your create trigger you wrote 'DISPENSE_DRUGS`, and because of this on any insertion in`DISPENSE_DOSAGES` trigger is not working coz it is actually not there to work.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_DISPENSE_DRUGS]
        ON [dbo].[DISPENSE_DOSAGES] AFTER INSERT     
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT [DISPENSE_ID]
                    FROM INSERTED
                    WHERE 
                    [DISPENSE_ID] IN (SELECT [DISPENSE_ID] FROM [DISPENSE_DOSAGES]
                        WHERE [SEPARATE_ITEM] = 1)))
                            BEGIN
                                UPDATE 
                                [Integra].[dbo].[DISPENSE_DRUGS]
                                SET QUANTITY_DISPENSED = 0,QUANTITY_OWED = QUANTITY_PRESCRIBED
                                WHERE [DISPENSE_ID] IN (SELECT [DISPENSE_ID] FROM INSERTED)  --This line generates issue
                            END
    END
```

Comment: Sorry, it was old code. But trigger is on DISPENSE_DOSAGES table and I am updating DISPENSE_DRUGS table.

Comment: 343597781504 is the DISPENSE_ID which I am inserting into DISPENSE_DOSAGES table & comparing with Inserted Table